# Powershell -AllMatches

Tags: powershell

The problem I'm having is even though the value is 24 is goes to not else, any help would be greatly appreciated

```
# Export current secuirty policies
secedit /export /cfg  $programdata\secu.inf /quiet

$SecurityPolicyFile = $programdata + "\secu.inf"

$FileContent = Get-Content $SecurityPolicyFile

#CHECK COMPLIANCE

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#1.1.1 Enforce password history - 24 passwords remembered

$Matches = Select-String -InputObject $FileContent -Pattern "PasswordHistorySize = 24" -AllMatches

$IsAMatch = $Matches.Count

if ($IsAMatch -eq 24) {
  "1.1.1 Enforce password history - 24 passwords remembered .- In Compliance " + (Get-Date).ToString() >> $logfile
  $failed = $failed + 1
} else {
  "1.1.1 Enforce password history - 24 passwords remembered .- Not In Compliance " + (Get-Date).ToString() >> $logfile
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$Matches` is an [automatic variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables). Do not use it like that. Also, the output of `Select-String` doesn't have a property `Count`. The `Matches` property of that result does, though. But even then, the count would give you the number of matches, whereas it seems that you're actually after the number of remembered passwords.

Change this:

```
$Matches = Select-String -InputObject $FileContent -Pattern "PasswordHistorySize = 24" -AllMatches

$IsAMatch = $Matches.Count

if ($IsAMatch -eq 24) {
```

into this:

```
$m = Select-String -InputObject $FileContent -Pattern "PasswordHistorySize = (\d+)" -AllMatches

$IsAMatch = -not [bool]($m.Matches | Where-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value -ne 24 })

if ($IsAMatch) {
```

Comment: Thank you , Ill give that a shot.